# Find the length of the curve defined by the equation: $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{a}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the length of the curve defined by the equation:
$$\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{a}$$
from point $(0, a)$ to point $(a, 0)$.

Well, I decided to plot it as I didn't have intuition about how the graph actually looked. Let's take $a=3$:

[image]

Note that the graph doesn't actually "reach" $(3, 0)$ and $(0,3)$. Why does this happen?

I am only familiar with the formula $$l=\int_a ^b \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx,$$ where $f(x)$ is a given function and $f'(x)$ is its derivative. This doesn't seem applicable here, or is it? What's the correct way to approach the problem?

Comment: The curve is $y=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{x})^2$.

Comment: You can use parametric equations like $x=t^2$ and $y=(\sqrt{a}-t)^2$.

Comment: @MathStudent of course the graph reaches the points. The plotting engine just doesn't show it. [Try WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sqrt%5Bx%5D%2BSqrt%5By%5D%3DSqrt%5B3%5Dfrom+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+3+and+0%3C%3Dy%3C%3D3)

Comment: What about parametrization with trigonometric functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that $(a, 0), (0, a)$ don't appear on the plotted graph is an artifact of the plotting system. As you hint, both points satisfy the equation, hence they are part of the graph.

**Hint** The formula you mention for the arc length of a graph can be used here, all that remains is to solve the equation
$$\sqrt x + \sqrt y = \sqrt a$$
for $y$ as a function of $x$---
$$y = (\sqrt x - \sqrt a)^2 .$$
---and substitute in the arc length formula:
$$\int_0^a \sqrt{1 + \left(1 - \frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt x}\right)^2} \,dx .$$

> Substituting $u = \sqrt\frac{x}{a}$ transforms the integral to $$2 a \int_0^1 \sqrt{2 u^2 - 2 u + 1} \,du ,$$ which can be handled, e.g., by completing the square and using an appropriate hyperbolic substitution.

**Remark 1** Eliminating the radicals from the equation gives the equation of a parabola,
$$x^2 - 2 x y + y^2 - 2 a x - 2 a y + a^2 = 0 ,$$
so the curve is an arc of a parabola and in particular we know in advance that the arc length can be expressed in closed form in terms of elementary functions (which is not true for arc lengths of general plane curves!).

**Remark 2** This curve is (an arc) of a special case of a [**Lamé curve**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), in this case also a **hypoellipse**.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you! Is the answer $a\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)?$

Comment: @MathStudent Yes, that's what I get. You can also write it as $a \left(1 + \frac1{\sqrt 2} \operatorname{arsinh} 1\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

To find the length of the curve defined by the equation $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=\sqrt{a}$ from point $(0, a)$ to point $(a, 0)$ (with $a> 0$), we can use the arc length formula for parametric curves.

Let's parameterize the curve by letting $x = t^2$ and $y=(\sqrt{a}-t)^2$. This parameterization ensures that we traverse the curve from $(0, a)$ to $(a, 0)$.

You can calculate the derivative of $x$ and $y$ with respect to $t$:

$$
\frac{dx}{dt}\quad \text{and} \quad \frac{dy}{dt} 
$$

and you can use the formula for the arc length of a parametric curve:

$$
L = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2} \, dt
= \int _0 ^a \sqrt{8t^2-8\sqrt{a}t+4a}\,dt
$$

Completing the square, we have

$$\sqrt{8t^2-8\sqrt{a}t+4a}=\sqrt{2 a + 8 (t-\sqrt a/2)^2}$$

Comment: I am a little confused, how did you find the parametrisation of the curve?

Comment: @MathStudent Squaring the equation.

Comment: And what is a possible way to integrate $$\int _0 ^a \sqrt{8t^2-8\sqrt{a}t+4a}(dt)$$

Comment: @MathStudent. Complete the square and let $t=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{a}+u\right)$

Comment: @MathStudent I have done an edit.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you! Is the answer $a\left(1+\dfrac{\ln(1+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)?$

Comment: @MathStudent You're welcome. I shoud do the integral :-(....I don't know.